# use jquery to manipulate dom objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a CMS which builds navigation with text based anchors only so its current output is

```
<li class="socialLinks"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</a></li>
```

I need to manipulate these links to work with font awesome. Essentially I want to remove the anchor text but at the same time using it to have a class appear on an icon element. The final list elements should look like this. So take the anchor text of "facebook" and adding it to the second icon element as a class of fa-facebook.

```
<li class="socialLinks"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span></a></li>
```

I was attempting to use .prepend to find the .socialLinks a element and prepending the anchor text with jQuery like so. And this works, I just can't figure out how to now take the anchor text and convert it to fa-facebook and add it to the icon with class of .fa-stack-1x. And then remove the anchor text altogether.

```
$('.socialMediaLinks a').each(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span>');
});
```

this returns

```
<li class="socialLinks"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span>Facebook</a></li>
```

What is the best course of action. Secondly should I put this on document ready or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of of [this property of .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)) to replace html aware of the previous html in each element:

```
$('.socialMediaLinks a').html(function(i, html) {
      var mediaclass = 'fa-' + $.trim(html).toLowerCase();
      return '<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> <i class="fa fa-stack-1x ' + mediaclass + '  fa-inverse"></i> </span>';
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RBzwk/

Comment: That works to remove the facebook anchor text. How do I take facebook anchor text, convert it to a class on the icon element. So facebook becomes a class of fa-facebook on the second icon element

Comment: What would you like the class to be ? just `facebook`? And on the span I guess right?

Comment: fa-facebook on the `<i class="fa fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">`. However if the anchor text is twitter it would have to be fa-twitter etc.

Comment: Works great. Just never even thought to use a variable. Thanks alot. I had been stuck on this for about an hour. I will mark as answered. Thanks